# ETXJS 6.2.0 Combobox Filter Returns Mulitple Values

Tags: extjs, combobox, filtering, extjs6.2

I have a combobox that's filtering a store based on an id from another drop down. However the filter seems to be returning all the values that **START** with the selected id.

```
xtype: 'combobox',
name: 'actor',
fieldLabel: 'Actor',
typeAhead: true,
forceSelection: true,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
bind: {
  store: 'actorStore',
  value: 'actor.id',
  filters: [{
    property: 'customerId',
    value: '{customer.value}',
    disableOnEmpty: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the filter's operator, see [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.util.Filter.html#cfg-operator):

```
filters: [{
    property: 'customerId',
    value: '{customer.value}',
    operator: '=',
    disableOnEmpty: true
}]
```

(I don't know your ExtJS version, but I am not sure the combobox has a `filters` config, but the store surely has.)